# Не работает mysql.dll

Tags: windows, администрирование, windows-server-2008-r2

Для одной из программ, а именно модуля для 1C, требуется mysql.dll. Но после регистрации компонента в "Службе компонента", программа также выдает ошибку связанную с неработоспособностью этого компонента. Сделано всё правильно, также проверяла установку компания разработавшая модуль. На локальной машине модуль исправно работает, а на сервере нет.

Есть, единственное предположение, что какие-то компоненты или служба безопасности блокирует работу его, но в логах нет никакой информации. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался, подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: 1с в качестве бэкенда вроде `pg` юзает или я чё-то не знаю?

Comment: @donRumata Это не важно. Модуль выгружает товар в MySQL базу на стороннем сервере.

Comment: Фаервол пробовал отрубить?

Comment: @donRumata он отключен, и других ошибок в логах нет. Единственное предположение что это из-за 64х разрядной платформы 1C на сервере. Так как модуль писался для 32. Хоть и запускаем с 32-разрядного клиента, похоже этого недостаточно.

Comment: Ну тогда поднять тестовое окружение на 32 битах и проверить.

Comment: Нашел проблему. Через некоторое время работы включался безопасный режим и отключал ком объект.

Comment: @ИванАнтонов По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.